# Wine does not work

Tags: 20.04, wine

I've installed, uninstalled, tried stable, staging, YouTube tutorials and nothing seems to work in order to make Wine work.

After the `winecfg` stage, all videos and guides I have seen show Wine as an option when clicking *Open with other application*. However, I cannot find it.

I rebooted to check if there was something to do with that, but it wasn't. To be honest I don't want to mess something up.

This is what I see:

[image: winecfg]

I click *OK* and everything should run smoothly, but I go to any .exe file and can't do much, except of using the archive manager.

Wine should be here, right?

[image: Select application window]

I'd appreciate any help at all, even if the solution is setting up a VM.

Edit: Thanks, everyone for the help, I will use VirtualBox.

Comment: to be honest I suggest you to avoid wine because rarely it works.

Comment: Try to install [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)  and download a windows image from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Answer (score 2):

Wine is not an *application*, so it doesn't show up on the list of applications.

Wine is a *compatibility layer*. It's not a Windows emulator.

Reminder: Wine has never claimed to be 100% compatible with all Windows .exe files. Lots don't work at all. Others start (or stop) working after a version update. This is due to the Windows source code being unavailable to the Wine developers.

In the file manager (not the Desktop), try right-clicking on the .exe file in the file manager and choose “Run in Wine Compatibility Layer”

Or open a terminal and run wine explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have some bad items in your sources list. If you are running Ubuntu, wine-stable shouldn't have a xenial version. The baseline version of wine-stable in 18.04 is 3.0-1ubuntu1. I recommend removing all ppas that have to do with wine and attempt installing it from the baseline repos.

Answer (score 0):

you should try running this command in your Terminal `cp /usr/share/doc/wine/examples/wine.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/`
. It will load the wine.desktop file. this file allows the Wine Windows Program Loader to appear in the Other Applications Section of the File Manager
. I had the same problem and used this command to fix the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).